# Road Names - Multiple Lines and Single Lines

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, ordnance-survey

[image]Fairly new to the GIS world. I have been creating maps for my employer using OS Vector map data. Up until recently everything has been going smoothly - I only use vector based data so that I can adjust the colours and styles of the map. However, the only issue I have is the road names when compared to a rasterized version.

The rasterized version (Above) includes all road names using a variety of different placements. How can I replicate this using vectors and QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually specify letter kerning and other options in QGIS 3.10 and above, as well as make use of the Label Options toolbar, which will allow you to manually place individual labels.
[image]

See this great overview from Randall Hale on the earlier Label Toolbar functionality from QGIS 3.0, which has been slowly & steadily improved as updates to the 3.x branch have occurred.

https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-labeling-toolbar

For labels that are tricky and refuse to be placed properly, you can force them to be drawn by adjusting the Automated Placement Engine settings like so:
[image]

You find this by going to the Label tab in the layer properties, and clicking the cog in the top right to adjust the label engine global settings:
[image]

Comment: Hi Saijin, thanks for you reply, do you know if there's a way to automatically select the road names missing and adjust the placement?

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to address this. Thanks for helping me improve it!